# Flutter ajax call with multiple values and files

Tags: flutter, dart, upload

how i can send multiple data in Flutter. Mi data like so:

[from debug state of children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOnlT.png)

i have dynamic list with children
a child have name and birthday and a list of images!

I would like to send the entire data set to the server so that it is clear which picture belongs to which child. How do I do that in Flutter?

My code:

```js
class SaveChildren {
  List children = [];
  List childrenData = [];
  int serviceId;

  SaveChildren({this.serviceId, this.children});

  Future<http.Response> saveChildren() async {
    for (var i = 0; children.length > i; i++) {
      childrenData.add({
        'geburtsdatum': children[i].birthDay,
        'name': 'leer',
        'vorname': 'leer',
        'nachweise': children[i].imageFiles,
      });
    }

    var _url = "${Domains().APIDomain}/antrag/${serviceId}/uebernimmKinder";

    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("PATCH", Uri.parse(_url));
    request.fields['antragId'] = serviceId.toString();
    request.files.add(
      http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'kinder',
        utf8.encode(json.encode(childrenData)),
        contentType: MediaType(
          'application',
          'json',
          {'charset': 'utf-8'},
        ),
      ),
    );
    try {
      await request.send();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```